# Fineos java packaged solution

Tags: java

I am working on the fineos packaged solution which is based on Java. I am curious about a couple of things:

1. Though there are literally hundreds of class files and multiple jar in this packaged solution, there is only 1 class file with a main() method which is used for a standalone file extract. Others are all class files representing a business feature. The front end UI is in java script.

This packaged solution runs on the IBM WebSphere server.

How does java run this packaged solution with no main() method?. or does it use a different framework?. Or is main() no longer necessary for web applications?

2. How can any change on class files be tested in eclipse, as there are multiple dependencies associated?. I have so far mimicked the change as a stand-alone simple test.

Comment: `Or is main() no longer necessary for web applications?` - it never was. Time to read [java servlet specification](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/).

Comment: main is necessary for standalone applications, as the entry point of the application. Seeing as you're talking about a service, and not a standalone application, it doesn't need an entry point. The requests/urls/... will trigger the correct methods in the backend.